# How to fix "Android options" missing & can't open

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

"**Android options**" missing and not showing any info/settings.

I'm using **Visual Studio 2019 Xamarin** (*Android*)

[image: Screenshot]

I've tried to install everything in the SDK and still not working.

The "Android options" is missing/blank.

**Shows in the error when I click the blank:**
*"An error occurred trying to load the page.
Unable to create the designer.  The file is already opened in an incompatible editor.*"

Comment: Have you tried to delete the Bin and Obj folders? Many times it works.

Comment: where to locate this

Comment: Close VS, go to your project folder and inside there are those 2 folders.

Comment: Did you try to repair your VS in the VS installer.https://imgur.com/a/yykiya7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would suggest you try to update visual studio as microsoft published a fix for the problem like 5 hours ago, and I think is the same as yours as descirbed here:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/515660/cant-open-android-options.html

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/comments/143490/view.html 
ist wohl etwas mit deinem root certificate

Comment: I'm downloading the 4.67GB update.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes#16.2.0